# Multiple Selects in SP to return one recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im Using MS SQL and have a section of code that requires multiple basic SP's to run what I would like to do is compress them done to one.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_JOB_IMPORT_MULTICALL
(
@driverid as int,
@vehicleid as int,
@place as nvarchar(50)
)
AS  
 DECLARE @imval as int

BEGIN
    SET @imval = (SELECT ad.ImportValue FROM Admin AS ad WHERE ad.ID=1) +1
END

BEGIN
   SELECT DriverID,[JM ID] FROM Drivers WHERE DriverID=@driverid
   SELECT [Unit ID],[External JM ID] FROM Vehicles WHERE [Unit ID] = @VehicleID
   SELECT ImportValue FROM admin WHERE ID=1
   SELECT Dwelltime FROM Places WHERE Placename = @place
   SELECT [JM External ID] FROM Places WHERE Placename = @place
END
    UPDATE ADMIN SET ImportValue = @IMVAL WHERE ID=1


    RETURN
```

How can I do this and return it as a single record set ie

Driver ID, JM ID, Unit ID,External JM ID, Import Value, Dwell Time, Jm External ID

1------------1--------1--------1--------------------1-----------------1--------------1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they each return only one row, you can use `CROSS JOIN` to combine them:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [JM ID] FROM Drivers WHERE DriverID=@driverid) d CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT [Unit ID],[External JM ID] FROM Vehicles WHERE [Unit ID] = @VehicleID) v CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ImportValue FROM admin WHERE ID=1) a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT Dwelltime FROM Places WHERE Placename = @place) p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT [JM External ID] FROM Places WHERE Placename = @place) p2;
```

If they return more than one value, then you need to explain how the results are combined into a single row.

Comment: @user3652973 . . . I misphrased that.  I meant one row (and exactly one row).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am curious if that would be better with union with null on rest?

Comment: @brykneval . . . That would require an additional aggregation.  It is definitely a viable alternative solution.